# check the result object value is valid in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to validate the result(result_query) object with  other two objects in javascript,
Here, I need to check the result_obj is valid with other two objects have detailed view,if result_obj is valid then return true, or else false.

I have tried by using function `checkValidParamters` in javascript but looks messy but is there any alternative method in javascript.

```
function checkValidParamters(paramValue, result_query, obj_cn, obj_ccy) {
  var sendcountry, valid_country, valid_sccy, valid_rccy, valid;
  sendcountry = obj_cn.filter(function (send) {
    return send.country_name == paramValue[0];
  })
  if (sendcountry != '' && query !== '{}') {
    var r_c= obj_ccy.filter(function (rccy) {
      return rccy.currency == result_query.rccy;
    })
    for (var i = 0; i <= sendcountry[0].popular_to.length; i++) {
      if (sendcountry[0].popular_to[i] == paramValue[1]) {
        valid_country = true;
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= sendcountry[0].currency_from.length; i++) {
      if (sendcountry[0].currency_from[i] === result_query.sccy) {
        valid_sccy = true
      }
    }
    if (r_c[0].country_name == paramValue[1]) {
      valid_rccy = true;
    }
    if (valid_country && valid_sccy & valid_rccy) {
      valid = true;
      return valid;
    }
  }
    valid = true;
    return valid;
  }
  else {
    valid = false;
    return valid;
  }
}
```

```
/* result object */
var result_query= {
  send_country: 'Singapore', // check if exist in obj_cn 'country_name'
  sccy: 'SGD', // check if exist in obj_cn 'country-from'
  receive_country: 'India', // check if exist in obj_cn'popular_to'
  rccy: 'INR' // check if exist in obj_ccy 'currency' by using receive_country 
}
/*if all exists return true , if single value doesnot exist return false*/


/* others object */
var paramValue = ["Singapore", "India"];
var obj_cn = [
{
  country_name: "Singapore",
  country_from:["SGD", "USD"],
  popular_to: ["India", "UnitedStates"],
  country_to: ["SGD"],
  country_code: "SG"
},
{
  country_name: "Malaysia",
  country_from:["MYR"],
  popular_to: ["Singapore", "UnitedStates"],
  country_to: ["MYR"],
  country_code: "MY"
}
]
var obj_ccy = [
{
   currency: "SGD",
   country_code: "SG",
   country_name: "Singapore"
},
{
   currency: "INR",
   country_code: "IN",
   country_name: "India"
},
{
   currency: "USD",
   country_code: "US",
   country_name: "UnitedStates"
}
]
```

Expected Output
(if valid)
Result  = true
(if not valid)
Result  = false

Comment: `result_obj is valid with other two objects`  - What does it mean? What validity criteria is?

Comment: @Alexander result_obj values should match with other objects , for example, send_country : singapore if exists in other objects(obj_cn) likewise all exists, return true else false

Comment: @Alexander updated the edits, if you know alternative method please share, thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: It would be far easier if the keys matched....

Comment: @zer00ne thanks for prompt reply can you send me sample please